# How to explode string after \ in php

Tags: php, explode

I have a requirement where username is entered as **textdev\userid**

I need to get the userid from this string,I have tried using explode but it's not working with "\".

Can anybody suggest me how to extract the userid from this string in php.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:-

```
<?php

$inputString = "textdev\userid";
$userId = explode("\\",$inputString)[1];
echo $userId;

?>
```

We need to escape special characters in regex with \, therefore \\ will result to escape \

Output:-

```
userid
```

Comment: It's working Perfect,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `\`.  So use `\\` while exploding.

Comment: Not working, This is what I am using currently   $parts = explode('\\', $entered_username);

Comment: What is the actual content of `$entered_username`

Comment: try the other solution provided by nandal that would work.